# Error when running powrshell at prompt with TaskScheduler info - 'is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable ..'

Tags: powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm debugging why my script isn't running right in the TaskScheduler by running it at the command prompt in powershell ISE on the server like it's set up in TaskScheduler:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust> c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command "& .\\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust\RunScan_MoveFiles_Admin.ps1"
```

I get this error:

```
c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe : & : The term '.\\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust\RunScan_MoveFil
At line:1 char:1
+ c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -noninterac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (& : The term '....Scan_MoveFil:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
es_Admin.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & 
.\\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust\RunScan_MoveFiles_Admin.ps1
+   
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\\w5server\k...Files_Admin.p 
   s1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm not sure why it's splitting the full command line info like that in the error message either; hopefully it's not part of the problem.

I tried removing the '&' before the .\w5server...scriptname.ps1 but got the same error message.  I've never given a full path with this type of path before, but that's where the script is.  Last time I did this it was in c:\Scripts\B... on that server.

This server is Windows Server 2012 R2.  Previously, my server I was working on was 2008 R2, I'm not sure if that matters or not. Otherwise my syntax is the same, other than the script name and full path.

I saw this link [is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://www.alphr.com/the-term-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/), but I think it's spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with what I was using to run it at the command line, and this is working:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust> c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command \\w5server\ksupport\C_Adjust\RunScan_MoveFiles_Admin.ps1
```

So I got rid of the double quotes, '.' and '&' for the script location.